# How to Flatten a dictionary of (int, dictionary)?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have `SortedDictionary<int, Dictionary<string, HashSet<long>>>`

How can I flatten the result using Linq?

I've tried:

```
var result = dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x);
```

but how do I flatten to the very bottom?

I need to get a collection of `int, string, HashSet<long>`

Comment: What result do you want for the "flattened" data?

Comment: What exactly do you want to end up with? A collection of `HashSet<long>`? A collection of `long`? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use something like the following:

```
var flattened = dictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => (x.Key, y.Key, y.Value)));
```

This will produce an IEnumerable of `ValueTyple<int, string, HashSet<long>>`.

Note that because the type here is `IEnumerable`, it's not *yet* materialized. You might want to add a `.ToList()` to the end (in which case, the type will be `List<ValueTyple<int, string, HashSet<long>>>`) or convert it to any other collection type you desire.

Comment: Maybe you want to create a list as desired(collection) and avoid using `var` but `List<(int, string, HashSet<long>)>`, then it would be perfect +1

Comment: @Tim The OP didn't specify that they wanted a list. So, an IEnumerable can be converted to any collection type. If they want a list, they can simply append a `.ToList() to the end.

Comment: True, but `IEnumerable` <> `ICollection`, so it doesn't hurt to show how to create a real collection and it helps to understand your approach and the result to show the type. Collections implement `IEnumerable<T>` but your result is not a collection but a deferred executed LINQ query.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I've edited the answer to add that info.